# How is it possible to construct a std::vector of non-default constructible objects?

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across code like this from the [C++ reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v(l.begin(), l.end());
    return 0;
}
```

This is a snippet from the "Examples" section. The code compiles and runs as expected. But how is it possible? The `std::reference_wrapper<int>` is not default constructible. How can you make a `std::vector` of those things? I always imagined `std::vector` as a dynamic array. But how can you initialize a block of memory freshly given to you by OS in such a way from a `std::list`?

This may sound like a confusing question, but for some reason I cannot fully understand what is happening in the code above. What is going on in there?

Comment: I always thought it was initialized with null bytes and if there is a constructor, cal it.

Comment: Seems like you can't add to this kind of vector, but when it's being constructed it calls the non-default constructors for each element in `l`, like `std::reference<int>(-4)`, `std::reference<int>(-3)`, etc...

Comment: @Robl: Yes, you can add to it, using any method that doesn't require a default constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley `emplace_back`?

Comment: @balki: Yeah, that.  Or `emplace`, or `insert`, or `push_back`, or `resize` (the 2 argument version).  Actually, the only vector methods that require a default constructor is the single argument version of resize, and the constructor that just takes a int argument for an initial size (or an int and an allocator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `std::vector<>` first obtains a block of raw memory of appropriate size (using its `allocator`). It then constructs the objects. In case of the particular constructor here

```
template<typename It>
std::vector::vector(It begin, It end);
```

it constructs the elements from the valuetype of the iterators, thus each `reference_wrapper<int>` is constructed (in place) from an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

It works because there's no default initialization there - the elements from the list are used to copy-initialize the vector.

The following, for example, wouldn't work:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v(42);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. If I write a template class, is it ok for some methods not to work for all template type parameters? Is this considered good practice or is it just a privilege of the standard library?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: it is possible with some restrictions. As long as the method is not instantiated, then it's OK; however sometimes a method can be instantiated without you asking to, for example `virtual` method are always instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

All the objects in the vector are constructed using a one argument constructor that takes an int. So that's why you don't need a default constructor semantically.

As far as the implementation is concerned, this behavior can be implemented by allocating the memory with `malloc` instead of `new` (so no constructor is being called) and then using placement `new` when elements are added to the vector.

Comment: So that is the magic here. I always thought that the std::vector uses new internally. This makes sense.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik it could use `new` internally -- but `new unsigned char[size*sizeof(T)]` instead of `new T[size]`.